# Vector into varargs

Tags: c++, vector, exec

I have (all std) a `vector<string>` that I would like to push into `execl`, such that each member of my vector is passed in as a `char*`. Is this possible and if so how do I achieve it?

Comment: Hi! Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Convert it to a vector of `char const*`, and use `execv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, but you can use `execv` instead.  `execl` takes a variable-length **l**ist of arguments, whereas `execv` takes a **v**ector (really a C array).  You will however have to convert from your `std::vector<std::string>` to a C array of strings (`char **`).  Also `execv` requires a null-terminated array, that is, the last element of the array needs to be a null pointer.  But something like this should work:

```
int exec_my_vector(std::string path, std::vector<std::string> v)
{
    const char *cv[v.size() + 1];
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cv[i] = v[i].c_str();
    cv[i] = NULL;
    return execv(path.c_str(), (char * const *)cv);
}
```

(Disclaimer: there's a hideous cast at the end of the `execv` call that shouldn't be necessary, but I can't figure out a way around it.)

Comment: Also worth nothing that the conversion doesn't need more storage than the vector of pointers itself. It can be populated by calling `c_str()` on each element of the original vector.

Comment: @SteveSummit Expression must have a constant value. Attempt to access run-time storage. Variable length arrays are a C99 feature.